# DC-DC fixed voltage output converter and EMI Design, where to begin and roadmap?

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, inductance, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

I'm in a group of people tasked to design and implement a DC-DC converter with an output voltage of 24 volts, with an input voltage from 9 to 36V, with an EMI filter, which must comply with the EN50155 standard.
Read lots of papers but still having trouble where to start.
Should I begin with common mode and differential mode chokes design?
But in which range of frequencies must I attenuate?
I found formulas to find ferrite core permeability and circular mils. But still don't know where to start or simulate these in a program.
Hope to get a direction and instructions from an experienced person.

Comment: Build. Test. Modify design as needed. Repeat. Plan on doing it 3 times to be safe. Simulating for EMI is exceptionally difficult. I would not bother trying to do it. If you are able to put a common mode choke on cabling that leaves the board, that will help. If you are able to shield the cable that leaves the board, that will help. If you are able to enclose everything in a metal box, that will help. If you do all three (chokes and a metal box) you are almost guaranteed to find a passing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention EN 50155, so Railway Applications - Onboard. The reference EMC standard is indeed the EN 50121-3-2 for immunity, and EN 61000-6-4 for emissions (Industrial env.).

Now, it seems you are focusing on emissions: of course a DC/DC switching converter will have common mode emissions, that are relevant for compliance to conducted limits (up to 30 MHz) and radiated (above 30 MHz). This is the division of frequency ranges as per CISPR and EN 61000-6-4. be careful that the rolling stock item (e.g. loco or electro-train, or what) must pass EN 50121-3-1 that measures radiated emissions starting from 150 kHz. So, radiated emissions between 0.15 and 30 MHz from the DC/DC and its cables may be relevant to the overall compliance.

Then, the DC/DC conv may disturb others, as it will supply for sure some signaling or telecom equipment, maybe in the driver cab, or some Wifi AP along the train, or similar. In particular for special equipment such as driver's console, rather than a WiFi AP, the protocols used to send signals back and forth may be susceptible to coupling of noise through the respective functional grounds or to crosstalk. You do not have specs for this, because it's not compulsory, but knowing possible victims ("neighbors") and possible coupling paths beforehand will increase acceptance of your DC/DC product.

To come down to some figures, without knowing your power rating (i.e. the size of your DC/DC) usually a common-mode inductor around some mH works quite well; consider that if you include capacitors, they will need "ground", and onboard that ground is chassis, and everybody -- almost -- connects to it. So better relying on a good cm inductor.

Frequency range: you must simulate first, measure then the emissions of your DC/DC to understand which type of ferrite you need: considering low frequency (the mentioned 150 kHz for compliance to standards, lower than that for compliance with "neighbors"), you need  "soft" ferrite, e.g. 3E25 by Ferroxcube or equivalent (you need to build up the some mH we spoke of); high frequency can be cured with a ferrite toroid directly on the cable.

Of course, this is approximate and based on experience, pointing the finger to the major issues and elements. You should be more quantitative, considering the converter architecture, typical waveforms and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> *Hope to get a direction and instructions from an experienced person.*

You begin by reading the EMC parts of EN50155 (and referenced documents) and decide what range of frequencies you need to apply filters to and to what level of attenuation you might expect. Of course you can't decide how much attenuation you need to apply (and at what frequencies) until you have tested your basic converter design.

So, it's a two-pronged voyage of discovery - understand the requirements and understand how much filtering your design requires to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a design from an I.C. Manufacturer ( eg analog devices, texas inst., maxim). Every device will have some example circuits in its data sheet. Or, better yet, buy an evaluation board from the manufacturer that meets your voltage and current requirements.  Then follow the build, measure, refine advice of the other answers.